# Listener not firing in my activiy

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I am trying to add a click listener and a long click listener to my Main Activity but its not firing..  below is my code, don't know why its not firing, can someone tell me what i am missing?  Is it even possible to add a listener to the entire activity?

```
public class HomeFavesActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFavesCatovoty";
    private ArrayList<Integer> mIcons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    IconTray iconTray; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.v(TAG, "CREATED");

       DataBaseManager db = new DataBaseManager(this);
        /*db.getWritableDatabase();
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(1);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(2);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(3);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(4);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(5);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(6);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(7);*/

        getScreenIcons(db);

    }

    private void getScreenIcons(DataBaseManager db){
        mIcons = db.getScreenIcons("TestScreenIcons");
        Log.v(TAG, "List Length:"+  mIcons.size());

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);


        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        int screenWidth = metrics.heightPixels;
        int screenHeight = metrics.widthPixels;

        iconTray = new IconTray(this, mIcons, null, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        /*
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        params.addRule(rl.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        iconTray.setLayoutParams(params);*/
        rl.addView(iconTray);

        rl.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        rl.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void onClick() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "woot", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        iconTray.longClickMode();
        return false;
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        iconTray.clickMode();
    }




}
```

OK so now the LongClick Listener works but when if add the line for the click it won't publish because it generates an error..

**The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (HomeFavesActivity)**

Comment: Right now you just implemented the listeners, they are not attached to anything. You can't attach them to an `Activity` but you could try to add them to your layout's root element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate a view with the onclick listener.

ex.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then whenever you click your button it will call the listener you implement.
If you want to have your entire activity be selectable you can select the parent layout (like a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in your main.xml file) and follow the same code above but for that type of view.
Like so:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
parent.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: You are implementing a DialogInterface on click method. you must implement a View.OnClickListener. Delete your onclick method and make sure you are using View.OnclickListener in your implements line. Then try again :)

Comment: it will look like: 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    { } 
once implemented as opposed to the onClick you have implemented